# How to pass AxiosPrmoise type value while mocking axios.get using jest?

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, axios, typescript-typings

I tried the below code to mock axios.get() function, however typescript giving me "argument of type '{ data: expectedResult }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AxiosPromise<{}>'" error. 
Could someone help me how to handle this error?

```
    const expectedResult: string = 'result';

    const mock = jest.spyOn(axios, 'get');
    mock.mockReturnValueOnce({ data: expectedResult });

    const result = await sut.getFeed("testUrl");

    expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(result).toBe(expectedResult);
```

Answer (score 5):

I added AxiosResponse type return value from the mocked function and it works perfectly.

```
    const expectedResult: string = 'result';

    const feedResponsePromise = Promise.resolve({ data: expectedResult } as AxiosResponse);

    const mock = jest.spyOn(axios, 'get');
    mock.mockReturnValueOnce(feedResponsePromise);

    const result = await sut.getFeed("testUrl");

    expect(result).toBe(expectedResult);
```